# How to connect to aws Redshift db from mac

Tags: macos, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, sequelpro

I am using a mac and I typically use Sequel Pro to interact with sql databases. Usually I use mysql, but I understand redshift uses Postgres.

When I try to connect to my Redshift db, should I use the IP, or the "endpoint"?

Also when I try to connect, I get this error from Sequel Pro.

```
Unable to connect to host {{my_db_host}}, or the request timed out.

Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10 seconds).

MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '{{my_db_host}}' (4)
```

Can anyone offer advice on how to get connected?

Thanks

Comment: Just FYI, Redshift is based on ParAccel, which is a heavily modified fork of a very old version of PostgreSQL. It's a lot like saying "Drizzle uses MySQL".

Comment: Redshift is 90% PSQL, and particular things that are not have reasons for being that way to handle big data

Comment: @djc391 90% ancient PostgreSQL, yes. With a whole bunch of functions and features (like procedural languages) deleted. It's a useful product and there's nothing wrong with it, but it's really not PostgreSQL anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using the Redshift Endpoint, if you have your security group settings configured correctly. You might want to set your group to 0.0.0.0/0 during testing(this opens up your cluster to the entire internet, and you can lock it down later once it works)

You also need to make sure you have the correct ODBC/JDBC driver. I recommend either Netbeans(comes with connection driver), SQL Workbench, or Aginity Redshift. Default port is 5439.

I thikn you are using the wrong driver(a mysql driver not psql driver), becaues your error says MySQL server.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/gsg/rs-gsg-prereq.html

For mac, I believe you could also try and use the a terminal PSQL client. Something like...

```
psql -H endpoint.aws.com -p 5439 -U username --password
```

Comment: SQL Workbench is a nice option.  [Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.html#set-up-sqlworkbench)

Comment: for os x: `brew install postgresql`, then: `psql --host=hostname --port=5439 --dbname=dev --username=admin`